# Cannot get Highcharts solidgauge stops to work in styled mode

Tags: highcharts

I am converting all the charts in an application to Highcharts 5.x styled mode.

I cannot find how to make the solidgauge stops work in styled mode. When I inspect the SVG, I do not see any class for the colors.
I couldn't find any solidgauge stops example with styled mode.
Anyone can post a working example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a solid gauge series color is calculated dynamically based on stop values - currently, I do not think you can do the same with only css. The point `fill` atribute is calculated and set correctly but in this case css class takes precedence and the point's color has a fixed `fill` taken from the css file (highcharts-color-{n} class).

Keep stops in options and remove class from the point (or set colorIndex to a non existing number, e.g. 99)

```
.highcharts-color-0 {
   fill: #7cb5ec; //remove fill attribute
   stroke: #7cb5ec;
}
```

or:

```
data: [{y: 80, colorIndex: 99}], // the point's class will highcharts-color-99 now
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/gj8zfw73/